# Forcing Default Schema's in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, schema, administration

We are asking users to not create objects in their own schema (e.g. bill.Table rather than using dbo.Table). Ultimately, we want to force this rather than "ask nicely". I've Googled around and found nothing obvious. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Clay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding users to your database, the `CREATE USER` command has an optional parameter, viz [WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173463.aspx)

The option to set a default schema for the user is also available in ManagementStudio under the database's Security / Users tree.

I'm not sure that you can specifically allow users access to create objects like tables in a database while at the same time preventing them `CREATE SCHEMA` access - the folk at dba.stackexchange might know.

Comment: Welcome :). Would recommend that you post to dba.stackexchange to see if you can trim permissions on schemas but not other DDL - this way they can't create new Schemas, and thus would have to use one of the the existing schemas.

Comment: Ultimately the fix is going to be making developers do work in dev rather than prod and allow the DBAs to promote where appropriate